# How to import a library from an internet or local link

Tags: python

I would like to import a library from a remote link, either on a remote computer or the internet. Similar to how javascript can import code from anywhere on the internet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This javascript code imports code from a web link. How can I do this in python.

Comment: This question has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300915/how-can-a-python-module-be-imported-from-a-url/58102363#58102363

Answer (score 4):

You would have to fetch the source code. Save it to a file. And then use one of the functions in the [imp module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) in order to load it.

```
def load_remote(address):
    r = requests.get(address)
    with open('tempfile.py', 'w') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
    imp.load_source('new_module', 'tempfile.py')
```

Obviously you would want to generalise that some more... but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the language has no support for this. 
What you can do is to write your own import function that downloads the module from Internet in a temporary folder and then imports it.