# Importing *.py from url

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

I want to import some python functions from url for security purposes.

I got a solution from here:
[How can a Python module be imported from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300915/how-can-a-python-module-be-imported-from-a-url)

It kind of works; I can run first function (func1) fine, but when I try to run second function (func2) then python says func2 is not defined, why is that so ?

**module.py**  on webserver:

```
def func1(string):
    data = string+"world"
    return data
def func2(string):
    data = string+"bar"
    return data
```

**main.py** on my pc:

```
import urllib
def import_py_from_url(URL):
    exec urllib.urlopen(URL).read() in globals()

import_py_from_url("http://somehost.com/module.py")

#try first function
str = "hello "
data = func1(str)
print (data) # OUTPUT: hello world

#try seccond function
str = "foo "
data = func2(str)
print (data) # OUTPUT: NameError: name 'func2' is not defined
```

Is it even possible to do what i am trying to achive ? Not much info about it around.

Comment: "i want to import some python functions from url for security purposes" - you're not even doing anything to authenticate the code you're grabbing off the internet. It could be anything! This is the exact opposite of a security mechanism.

Comment: at the end, module.py will be outside of public html, and accessed via php authentication. I just simplified it for the issue presentation.