# Import a Python Module from a GitHub Gist

Tags: python, github, gist

I like the idea of GitHub Gists. That's where I, and many others, keep their tiny but handy Python modules. It would be nice to be able to directly import them to Python. Something like this:

```
import gist(url) as myModule
```

Is this possible? Is the only way just to extract the text from the gist and run `eval` on it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300915/how-can-a-python-module-be-imported-from-a-url

Comment: That's basically running eval on the downloaded text. Not sure if it's the best way.

Comment: It is a bit outside the scope of your question, but [codeskulptor](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/) allows to import modules stored.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution would be to download the gist from the url using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Then take the file name and import it using `import example_file`. You could also use a for loop to import all modules found within a directory.

- Example for downloading files using requests - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/8625593
- Example for iteratively importing modules - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Can-we-iteratively-import-python-modules-inside-a-for-loop

I highly recommend not using `eval()` as when used with user input, can be used maliciously.